# Ansible looping through different item within the same task

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, ansible

I want to apply the specific tag or tags for the ec2 instance to the attached EBS volumes. Form the `amazon.aws.ec2_instance_info:` I get the all information for the ec2 and then with

```yaml
"{{ item | flatten |
    map(attribute='block_device_mappings') | flatten |
    map(attribute='ebs') | flatten |
    map(attribute='volume_id') }}"
```

we can extract the volume IDs, but it returns the list of IDs like below

```yaml
[
  vol-xxxxxxx,
  vol-zzzzzzz,
]
```

How to make sure for each loop it chooses one of the volume IDs and passes it to `amazon.aws.ec2_tag:`

playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Ansible Test Playbook
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - vars/regions.yaml

  tasks:
    - name: Gather information about all instances
      amazon.aws.ec2_instance_info:
        region: "{{ item }}"
      register: instance_info
      loop: "{{ region }}"

    - name: Copy tags from EC2 to EBS
      amazon.aws.ec2_tag:
        region: us-east-1
        resource: "{{ item | flatten |
                      map(attribute='block_device_mappings') | flatten |
                      map(attribute='ebs') | flatten |
                      map(attribute='volume_id') }}"
        state: present
        tags:
          "team": "{{ item | flatten |
                      map(attribute='tags') | flatten |
                      map(attribute='team') | join }}"
      loop: "{{ instance_info.results | map(attribute='instances') }}"
```

In addition to this, I want to iterate the list of regions

```yaml
region: 
 - us-east-1 
 - us-east-2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: ***"Each loop passes one of the volume ids to amazon.aws.ec2_tag"***

A: Declare *volume_ids* and *teams* (the same way you do it in the loop) and use them in the task

```yaml
    - amazon.aws.ec2_tag:
        region: "{{ item.1 }}"
        resource: "{{ item.0 }}"
        state: present
        tags:
          team: "{{ teams }}"
      loop: "{{ volume_ids|product(region) }}"
      vars:
        volume_ids: "{{ instance_info.results|
                        map(attribute='instances')|flatten|
                        map(attribute='block_device_mappings')|flatten|
                        map(attribute='ebs')|flatten|
                        map(attribute='volume_id') }}"
        teams: "{{ instance_info.results|
                   map(attribute='instances')|flatten|
                   map(attribute='tags')|flatten|
                   map(attribute='team')|join }}"
```

(not tested)

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    region: 
      - us-east-1
      - us-east-2

    instance_info:
      results:
        - instances:
            - tags:
                team: tag_X
              block_device_mappings:
                - ebs:
                    - volume_id: vol-xxxxxxx
            - tags:
                team: tag_Z
              block_device_mappings:
                - ebs:
                    - volume_id: vol-zzzzzzz

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          amazon.aws.ec2_tag:
            region: "{{ item.1 }}"
            resource: "{{ item.0 }}"
            state: present
            tags:
              team: "{{ teams }}"
      loop: "{{ volume_ids|product(region) }}"
      vars:
        volume_ids: "{{ instance_info.results|
                        map(attribute='instances')|flatten|
                        map(attribute='block_device_mappings')|flatten|
                        map(attribute='ebs')|flatten|
                        map(attribute='volume_id') }}"
        teams: "{{ instance_info.results|
                   map(attribute='instances')|flatten|
                   map(attribute='tags')|flatten|
                   map(attribute='team')|join }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l test_01

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => (item=['vol-xxxxxxx', 'us-east-1']) => 
  msg: |-
    amazon.aws.ec2_tag:
      region: "us-east-1"
      resource: "vol-xxxxxxx"
      state: present
      tags:
        team: "tag_Xtag_Z"
ok: [test_01] => (item=['vol-xxxxxxx', 'us-east-2']) => 
  msg: |-
    amazon.aws.ec2_tag:
      region: "us-east-2"
      resource: "vol-xxxxxxx"
      state: present
      tags:
        team: "tag_Xtag_Z"
ok: [test_01] => (item=['vol-zzzzzzz', 'us-east-1']) => 
  msg: |-
    amazon.aws.ec2_tag:
      region: "us-east-1"
      resource: "vol-zzzzzzz"
      state: present
      tags:
        team: "tag_Xtag_Z"
ok: [test_01] => (item=['vol-zzzzzzz', 'us-east-2']) => 
  msg: |-
    amazon.aws.ec2_tag:
      region: "us-east-2"
      resource: "vol-zzzzzzz"
      state: present
      tags:
        team: "tag_Xtag_Z"

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_01                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, I've tried the product before but it skips the tagging, it seems that it is not doing regions one by one, I expect that like the first play is getting the info about us-east-1 and then with those info it goes to the next play and after tagging it goes for the next region and again do the tagging, but it not the current behavior. When I hardcore the region it is working then!!

Comment: I added an example for testing. Tell me if it's not working.

Comment: Hi again Vladimir, and thanks for your answer, but I can't use:
 instance_info:
      results:
        - instances:

as variables, because Im talking about more than 100 accounts and regions, thats why Im using 

    - name: Gather information about all instances
      amazon.aws.ec2_instance_info:
        region: "{{ item }}"
      register: instance_info
      loop: "{{ region }}"
as the first play.

Comment: There is no reason that you `can't use: instance_info`. There is no difference in a registered or declared variable. Just the opposite! You have to understand what [mre] means. In terms of providing a **complete** example, you can't post a registered variable from 100 accounts because the **example** must be **minimal** at the same time. What you should do? You have to find the failing accounts, select and post the **minimal** *instance_info* that **reproduces** the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to post the complete answer in the yaml format in the comment section, lets forget about the 100 accounts, the instance_info is the registered variable from the first play, and in that play I used a loop for region.

Comment: You should post [mre] in the question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The section *Help others reproduce the problem* in particular.